# Correct way to make .p12/.pem and test APNS locally

Tags: python, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm unable to find any script which highlights how to create a .p12/.pem file and test push notification locally.

I find multiple ways of making the .pem file (with/without password, .key and .cer combined etc) and .p12 file but end up with an ssl error or invalid device token.

which script works and how do I create the certificate which it needs.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on using .pem and certificates, then the following code will work..

```
# setup:
# sudo apt-get install python35
# python select --set python python35
# sudo apt-get install py35-pip
# python select --set pip pip35
# sudo pip35 install Hyper


import ssl
import json
from hyper import HTTP20Connection
from hyper import tls

APNS_SANDBOX_HOST = 'api.development.push.apple.com'
APNS_PRODUCTION_HOST = 'api.push.apple.com'

class APNS(object):
    def __init__(self, sandbox=True):
        self.sandbox = sandbox
        self.port = 443
        self.host = APNS_SANDBOX_HOST if sandbox else APNS_PRODUCTION_HOST

        certificate_file = "./apns_dev.pem" if sandbox else "./apns_prod.pem"

        ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
        ctx.check_hostname = False
        ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
        ctx.load_cert_chain(keyfile=certificate_file, certfile=certificate_file)

        self.connection = HTTP20Connection(self.host, port=self.port, ssl_context=ctx, force_proto=tls.H2C_PROTOCOL)

    def push(self, uuid, topic, payload):
        headers = {
            "apns-topic": topic,
            "apns-priority": str(10),
            "apns-expiration": str(0)
        }

        self.connection.request("POST", "/3/device/{0}".format(uuid), payload, headers=headers)
        return self.connection.get_response()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    payload = {
        "aps": {
            "alert": {
                "title": "Hey",
                "body": "Test"
            },
            "sound": "default"
        }
    }

    apns = APNS()
    print(apns.push(uuid="device_uuid", topic="bundle_id", payload=json.dumps(payload)).read())
```

P.S. I highly recommend using jwt tokens instead of certificates. It is so much easier and doesn't expire and you don't have to worry about certificates and keys or anything.